# How should I handle heavy audio load with JavaScript/HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I'm building a little sequencer like [this one](http://safe.tumblr.com/safe/video/2509512839/500), but want to use HTML/JavaScript exclusively (i.e: no Flash).

As you play around with the applet in the link above, you'll notice the potential for several sounds to play simultaneously and/or in rapid succession. I'm using an array of `audio` objects simulating different 'slots' or channels to achieve the desired polyphony and, as a concept, this seems to work. I'm not experiencing any clipping or cutouts in my audio.

However, this process becomes prohibitively resource-intensive very quickly, regardless of source filetype/compression. It's not uncommon for the web browser itself to crash as the number of sounds playing increases.

So, I"m wondering: **What, if any, is the best way to facilitate a fairly heavy audio load without choking the browser?** Or, is trying to make HTML/JS work for this purpose a fool's errand?

Any insight would be much-appreciated. [Here](http://jsbin.com/afoqog/edit#preview) is a version without sound.

Comment: I could have hours of fun with that sequencer! I wish you luck building your HTML/JS one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant say myself, but here's some examples making use of the new web audio api.
http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/index.html
The drum machine is pretty taxing on my system, though. In any case, I figure you'd be interested in the link.

Comment: Thanks for the link! My system does okay with the drum machine, and I'm sure it's due in no small part to how efficiently it was programmed. The slowdown I'm experiencing may also be due to the DOM manipulation occurring to create the visual effects (see my second link above), but still, I wonder if there are any libraries that interface with the stock API to boost performance.

Comment: Well, it looks like this question is fading into oblivion. Thanks again for taking the time to answer, @Chris!